# Adding elemnts to a DOm structure with javaScript

Tags: javascript

i create a table with java script DOM but sth went wrong. First here is my code

```js
var tblBody = document.getElementById("cocktailtablebody");
for (var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");

  var cell = document.createElement("th");
  var cellText = document.createTextNode(mydata[i].name);
  cell.appendChild(cellText);
  row.appendChild(cell);

  let str = "<ul>";
  for (const [p, val] of Object.entries(mydata[i].ingredients)) {
    str += `<li>${p}:${val}</li>`;
  }
  str += "</ul>";
  var cell = document.createElement("td");
  var cellText = document.createTextNode(str);
  cell.appendChild(cellText);
  row.appendChild(cell);
  var cell = document.createElement("td");
  var cellText = document.createTextNode("1");
  cell.appendChild(cellText);
  row.appendChild(cell);
  var cell = document.createElement("td");
  var cellText = document.createTextNode("2");
  cell.appendChild(cellText);
  row.appendChild(cell);
}
```

But the result is

`<ul>` and `<li>` are not written as html tags they are written as normal text?

What is Wrong??

mydata is a json

```
 [
    {
        "name": "Rum & Coke",
        "ingredients": {
            "rum": 12,
            "coke": 48
        }
    }, ....]
```

Comment: Provide value for `mydata`

Comment: you're appending a string `.createTextNode(str)` if you want to dump the whole HTML, then you need at least to create a html element (a div for example) and append the `str` as `.innerHTML = str` ... or you need to create also nodes for `ul` and `li` 's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `innerHTML` to render the `ul` and `li` as html elements. Or else they will be treated as plain text.

Working example

```js
var tblBody = document.getElementById("cocktailtablebody");

const mydata = [
  {
    name: 'name', ingredients: {
      Inc1: 'Inc 1',
      Inc2: 'Inc 2',
      Inc3: 'Inc 3',
      Inc4: 'Inc 4',
    }
  }
];
for (var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");

  var cell = document.createElement("th");
  var cellText = document.createTextNode(mydata[i].name);
  cell.appendChild(cellText);
  row.appendChild(cell);

  let str = '<ul>';
  for (const [p, val] of Object.entries(mydata[i].ingredients)) {
    str += `<li>${p}:${val}</li>`;
  }
  str += '</ul>';
  var cell = document.createElement("td");
  var cellText = document.createElement('div');
  cellText.innerHTML = str;
  cell.appendChild(cellText);
  row.appendChild(cell);
  var cell = document.createElement("td");
  var cellText = document.createTextNode("1");
  cell.appendChild(cellText);
  row.appendChild(cell); var cell = document.createElement("td");
  var cellText = document.createTextNode("2");
  cell.appendChild(cellText);
  row.appendChild(cell);
  tblBody.appendChild(row);
}
```

```html
<div id="cocktailtablebody"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have raw html to append rather than creating proper elements, you can inject it directly by appending it to the innerHTML of your target element:

Try it example:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GRZGWUVWKKJ8

```
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML + '<li>newitem</li>'
```